# AES-256-CBC encryption in PHP and decryption in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography, aes

my problem is that I  encode a string in PHP with the m_crypt module in aes-256-cbc with base64 like this:

```
    function encrypt($data) {
        if(32 !== strlen($this->secret)) $this->secret = hash('SHA256', $this->secret, true);
        $padding = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
        $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

        $encrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->secret, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, str_repeat("\0", 16));

        return base64_encode($encrypt);
    }
```

Where $this->secret is a 32-bit aes key and $data is the string I want to encrypt.

This works fine, the text is encrypted and send to the server without any problems (I checked that twice!) and now i want to decode this whole thing with Node.JS like this:

```
    var decipher = Core.crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', rows[0]['sessionkey']);
    decipher.update(body.user, 'base64', 'utf8');
    var user = decipher.final('utf8');
```

Where Core.crypto is the require call of the normal crypto module in Node.JS, rows[0]['sessionkey'] is the key used for encryption recived via mysql request and body.user is the  PHP encrypted string send via post request.

As I mentioned, everything works fine, except for this little decypt thing... i searched google and everything and tried sample code, but it seems that something with my code is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself. I forgot to set the iv when decrypting the message in Node.js, the working code looks like this:

```
var key =  new Buffer(rows[0]['sessionkey'], 'binary');

function decipher(key, data) {
    var decipher = Core.crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key.toString('binary'), str_repeat('\0', 16));
    decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8');
    return decipher.final('utf8');
}
```

I hope this will help anyone in the future!

Best Regards