# NodeJS AES 256 hex decrypt error

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

Good day. I want to use nodejs module crypto to decode previously encoded string. String is encoded with AES 256 ECB and I have it as hex. All my attempts did nearly nothing, just sometimes I got null string instead of errors. I 'require' only crypto, no open-ssl.

**HEX**: 820D4DA01CE75046C399CA314C5428C6AF8D69C6573B4DE5A6942A5277936F56
**Key**: 7y05R9qwKaIKgIHh4vAw19X1zuknR21Y

Here's my nodejs code.

```
var algorithm = 'aes-256-ecb',
password = '7y05R9qwKaIKgIHh4vAw19X1zuknR21Y',
encString = '820D4DA01CE75046C399CA314C5428C6AF8D69C6573B4DE5A6942A5277936F56'

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password);
var dec = decipher.update(encString,'hex','utf8');
dec += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(dec);
```

And I have this error.

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt.
```

Need your help please.

**UPDATE**

After fome hours and priceless advices from Maarten Bodewes and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667938/aes-256-cbc-encryption-in-php-and-decryption-in-node-js), this is working solution.

```
var encString=req.query.d;
console.log(encString);

var algorithm = 'aes-256-ecb',
    password = new Buffer('7y05R9qwKaIKgIHh4vAw19X1zuknR21Y', 'binary');

var decipher=crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password.toString('binary'), '');
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var dec = decipher.update(encString,'hex','utf8');
dec += decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(dec);
```

Comment: Don't post a solution into the *question*. You can post an answer yourself.

Comment: @ArtjomB. You are right of course. In this case it though it mostly seems a workout of my answer, for the localized part of the question. Personally I like that more than somebody posting an answer based on my advice and accepting that one :) BadVolt, another option is to edit the code into the *answer* instead of the question as demonstration that the answer works. Glad you got it solved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `createDecipher` with algorithm, key and IV arguments. IV is likely ignored, but set it to 16 zero bytes just to be sure. If you use the two argument function then the key will be put through a password based key derivation function (PBKDF). And decryption with an incorrect key of course results in failure.

Make sure you switch off padding if decryption fails and see if the resulting plaintext makes any sense.

Comment: The result certainly doesn't make sense to me. Without encryption routine, this might be hard to solve.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't helped. Now I have Error: Invalid IV length;
Using this. `var iv = new Buffer([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);`